# Extracting numbers from string c++ regex

Tags: c++, regex

I'm trying to extract numbers from string:

```
string line = "00:00:15,000 --> 00:00:18,000";

smatch results;

bool found = regex_match(line, results, regex("(\\d\\d):(\\d\\d):(\\d\\d),(\\d\\d\\d) --> (\\d\\d):(\\d\\d):(\\d\\d),(\\d\\d\\d)"));

/*for (auto result : results) {
    cout << result << endl;
}*/

int res = atoi( *results[3] );
```

I can easily print results(the commented code) but i can't covert results to an int. Dereferencing doesn't work for some reason with this results array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In C++11, you should use [`std::stoi`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stol) to convert a `std::string` to integer. (And no need to dereference it; in fact, `*results[3]` is a compile-error since it is not a pointer.)

```
int number = stoi(results[3]);
cout << number << endl;  // 15
```